# Derivation of General form of Map Projections

Tags: differential-geometry, trigonometry, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry, map-projections

In [this](https://www.marksmath.org/classes/common/MapProjection.pdf) paper, the following formulae are derived for the cylindrical and conic projections:

**Cylindrical**: $T(\phi, \lambda)= (\lambda, h(\phi))$ for some function $h$.

Examples include:

- Equi-rectangular: $T(\phi, \lambda)= (\lambda, \phi)$
- Lambert's equal area: $T(\phi, \lambda)= (\lambda, \sin(\phi))$
- Gnomonic: $T(\phi, \lambda)= (\lambda, \tan(\phi))$
- Mercator: $T(\phi, \lambda)= (\lambda, \ln{(|\sec(\phi)+\tan(\phi)|)})$

**Conic**:
$$
\begin{aligned}
x&=\rho\sin(n(\theta-\theta_0)
\\ y &= \rho_0-\rho\cos{(n(\theta-\theta_0))}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\theta_0$ is the central meridian, $\rho_0$ is the distance between C and the circular arc representing the North pole, and $n$ is the ratio of the angle between meridians and their true angle (the *cone constant*).

$\theta_0$ is usually chosen by the cartographer whilst $\rho_0$ and $n$ are dictated by the desired properties of the map.

Examples include the Lambert conformal conic projection, Albers conic, Equidistant conic, etc.

**Question**
How can we derive these general formulae for the cylindrical and conic map projections?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Can you say a bit about your mathematical background? Particularly, have you seen vectors, parametric equations of lines, and so forth? It would also help to know what you mean by _derive_: Do you want to see that the stated mappings have the advertised properties, or do you want to know how to start with the desired properties and construct the mapping (which is harder)? <> Finally, MathJaX is strongly preferred for searchability and accessibility; if you're able to type the necessary formulas people here will surely appreciate it.

Comment: Hello, thank you for reaching out. 1) Yes, I am familiar with the basics of multivariable calculus and topics like parametric equations, spherical trigonometry, and vectors. 2) By _derive_, I wish to start with the desired properties and construct the general formulae (not just _show_ that it is true) 3) Edited, replaced the images with mathjax.

Comment: After looking over the linked notes, I'm not sure there's much to say other than 1. A cylindrical projection is characterized by longitude being one Cartesian coordinate and latitude being a function of the other coordinate, i.e., $T(\phi,\theta)=(x,y)=(\theta,h(\phi))$; 2. A conic projection is given by letting longitude be represented by a multiple of the polar-coordinate angle $\theta$ and the polar-coordinate radius $\rho$ be a function of latitude, hence the last set of equations.

Comment: Thank you, but geometrically speaking, why would letting "longitude be one Cartesian coordinate and latitude be a function of the other coordinate" make it a cylindrical projection? And ditto for conics.

Comment: Those seemed (to me) to be the author's definitions. If we wrap a cylinder around a globe, tangent along the equator, it's geometrically natural to use longitudinal planes to map (in the mathematical sense) the globe to the cylinder. Unwrapping the cylinder to a flat map then makes longitude one coordinate. If in addition this mathematical mapping "respects" rotation about the earth's axis, then latitude circles are sent to horizontal lines, i.e., $y$ is a function of latitude (alone, not of longitude). But is that what you're asking...?